# MOSS and the Business Data Catalog - any good documentation?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, bdc

Can anyone point to any good 'beginners walkthroughs' for the Business Data Catalog in MOSS 2007 Enterprise?  It seems to be very powerful, but all the official guides assume preexisting knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [SharePoint 2007 Developer's Guide to Business Data Catalog](http://www.manning.com/lonsdale/). The authors (Brett Lonsdale and Nick Swan) have been developing tools and working with the BDC for 'ages' and really know their stuff.

There is an early access available now with the final due to be published in September 2009.

Answer (score 2):

This has a great overview on the BDC, some examples on what it can do, and how to configure it:

http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/administration/everything-you-need-to-know-about-bdc-part-1-of-8

It's a really great starting place that will help you get better footing when proceeding on to the more technical sites & how-tos.  It's the best "starter" resource I've found yet.

Comment: That is a good article - it's split into 8 parts in different blog entries and unfortunately the intro article linked above doesn't have links to each of the 8 parts! Search using the tag BDC and you'll get links to all 8 parts - or go here: http://sharepointmagazine.net/?s=bdc

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BDC Metaman](http://www.lightningtools.com/bdc-meta-man/default.aspx), this tool will support you connecting to a BDC.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it a few months ago, and was able to display data from a db.  Do you have a problem you're trying to solve, or are you just trying to get an understanding of what you can do with it?

By "preexisting knowledge", do you mean of Sharepoint, or the BDC itself?

Check out these links, as a start:

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/In+the+Office/Introducing-the-Business-Data-Catalog-BDC/
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-4-SharePoint_2007__BDC_-_The_Business_Data_Catalog.aspx